# Enums and ngModel data binding in Ionic 4 / Angular 7

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, enums, angular7, ionic4

How does one achieve 2-way data-binding between an `enum` and an `ion-select`?

Example enum;

```
export enum FooEnum {
  Option_1 = 1,
  Option_2 = 2,
  Option_3 = 3,
  Option_4 = 4,
  Option_5 = 5,
}
```

Example component class;

```
export class Enums1Page implements OnInit {
    public dataVal = FooEnum.Option_4;
    get fooEnum() { return FooEnum; }
    ...
}
```

Example template;

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="dataVal"> 
     <ion-select-option *ngFor="let entry of fooEnum | keys" value="{{ entry.key }}">{{ entry.name }}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Note the `ion-select-options` above are created using a custom pipe, which works great.  However the actual data-binding of the currently-selected value is failing.

I suspect this is because internally, an enum evaluates as an integer, while the keys in `ion-select-option` appear to be handled as strings.  I can circumvent this problem with the following hack;

Added to my class;

```
get getFooEnum(): string {
    return this.dataVal.toString();
}
set getFooEnum(u: string) {
    this.dataVal = +u;
}
```

And adjusted in my HTML;

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="getFooEnum"> 
    ...
</ion-select>
```

In this way I'm able to provide a string version of the current Enum value, which the `ion-select` is about to 2-way bind with.

This is not optimal since it requires extra code for every Enum I want to use.

Is there a better way, perhaps a way to string-cast the two-way-bound enum value in the template- or some way to treat the `ion-select-option` values as integers?

Here's all of the code if you want a deeper look;

https://github.com/sygnaltech/ionic4UiPatterns/tree/master/src/app/enums1

NOTE: Ultimately, the pattern is part of a CRUD app, centered on a data transfer object.  The enum field will be a public field within that object.

Answer (score 0):

try to assign the enum value to a Property so that it can work

```
export class Enums1Page implements OnInit {
    public dataVal = FooEnum.Option_4;
    public fooEnum = FooEnum;
    // get fooEnum() { return FooEnum; } <-- this will impact on performance issue too
}
```

Comment: Hi Sheik, thanks for the performance tip, swapping out the `fooEnum` approach works fine, I'm not sure why the original code I found used the property approach, the template can bind just as easily to a field.

Comment: However converting `dataVal` to an enum-based get/set property doesn't fix the problem, it has to be a string. In fact, if I make it `dataVal = '4'`, it two-way binds just fine, but it's no longer an enum. I need some other means to transpose between string & enum, or to find some feature in `ion-select` that will allow enum binding in `[(ngModel)]`